# Symfony is adding to file size when downloading from controller

Tags: symfony, vichuploaderbundle

I have uploaded an image with the VichUploaderBundle am returning an image file like so:

```
/**
 * Show license image.
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function showImageAction(Request $request,$id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $license = $em->getRepository('MyCarBundle:License')->findOneById($id);

    $fileName = $license->getFrontName();
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $contents = '';
    $filePath = __DIR__ . '/../../../../app/uploads/licenses/'. $user->getId().'/'.$fileName;


    $response = new Response();
    $disposition = $response->headers->makeDisposition(ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_INLINE, $fileName);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', $disposition);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'image/jpg');
    $response->setContent(file_get_contents($filePath));

    return $response;
}
```

and in html im trying to show the image, like so

```
<img class="img-fluid w-100 u-block-hover__main--zoom-v1" src="{{ path('license_show_image',{'id':license.id}) }}" alt="Image Description">
```

The image was uploaded succesfully. When I open the image in the uploaded folder, it is showing fine.

But the image is not showing in the browser. while directly accessing the url, the image is downloading but it is not able to open.  It is giving me the following error:

```
The file “ODL_Eng_Full_Back-5.jpg” could not be opened.
```

Does anyone know whats going on?

**UPDATE:**

Symfony is adding ~700kb to the file size when downloading. after uploading it seems to have proper file size, but downloading adds file size. whats going on here?

**UPDATE 2:**

these are the headers:

```
Request URL:http://localhost/app-temp/web/app_dev.php/account/license/2/show-image
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:[::1]:80
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers
view source
Cache-Control:no-cache, private
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Disposition:inline; filename="ODL_Eng_Full_Back.jpg"
Content-Type:image/jpg
Date:Tue, 17 Oct 2017 23:31:02 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache/2.4.27 (Unix) PHP/7.1.8
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Debug-Token:0e53c1
X-Debug-Token-Link:http://localhost/app-temp/web/app_dev.php/_profiler/0e53c1
X-Powered-By:PHP/7.1.8
Request Headers
view source
Accept:image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:__atuvc=54%7C42; _ga=GA1.1.1906437920.1508087850; _gid=GA1.1.1258608977.1508087850; PHPSESSID=iuhk0pr0oqtaje5371fp7q7vfk
Host:localhost
Referer:http://localhost/app-temp/web/app_dev.php/account/creditcards/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `BinaryFileResponse` ([doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#serving-files)
) like:

```
$response = new BinaryFileResponse($filepath);
$response->headers->set('Content-disposition', sprintf('filename=%s', basename($filepath)));

return $response;
```

Comment: im getting an error on this: The content cannot be set on a BinaryFileResponse instance.

Comment: @apfz you cannot use the `setContent()` method if you use a `BinaryFileResponse`. It does what you need automatically (eg. reading and serving the file). Forget the `Content-Type` header aswell, the only thing you would need to worry about is the `Content-Disposition` header, if you prefer an `inline` or `attachment` file.

Comment: when I looked at this again I have found the issue. As I did not set setContent, I was confused on your comment initially. When looking at the error stack, it turns that the vihuvac/htmlcompressor bundle is messing with the response :S. thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 2):

EDIT : HTTP Response seems to be correct.

Since you're using VichUploaderBundle, why not just use its helpers ?

```
<img src="{{ vich_uploader_asset(license, 'frontName') }}" alt="{{ license.frontName }}">
```

Comment: directory namer was already in place and seems not relevant for the file download. the path has been properly set. The vice_uploader_asset wants to download from a public folder which hasn't been configured anywhere. im storing the files in a private folder.

Comment: Sorry I missed that point, you mean that the image folder is not publicly available, and you wish to dynamically render the image content?

Comment: yes thats correct. it seems that the image that im downloading differs from the one that is uploaded. the controller is exactly as in my question. have never experienced this.

Comment: Alright, your Response seems to be correct, even though as G1.3 suggested, BinaryFileReponse could be even easier ;

Are you sure your picture itself is a valid `jpg` file (and not `jpeg` for instance)? Not sure if that makes a difference...

What do you try to dump `strlen(file_get_contents($filePath))` ? Is it the same size as your physical file?

Comment: yes same file size (882 kb) when I dump it in showImage method. when downloaded through same method size jumps to 1.6 mb.

Comment: Can't really see a reason for that... Is it recurrent for all your pictures? Might be a problem of webserver configuration (eg. gzip?)

Could you please add the headers of the HTTP response returned by your controller? Such as Content-Length, Content-Type etc. ?

Comment: turned off gzip. have added the headers

Comment: Can't really see anything wrong down here... Just the `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` maybe, which would point a misconfiguration of the webserver but still... Could you possibly test using symfony's built-in webserver ? `php bin/console server:start -v`

Comment: Tried the Symfony server, but no luck :(

Comment: Alright... Is it recurrent for all uploaded files or is it just this special file? (might be corrupted for any reason) And have you tried using `BinaryFileResponse` instead (without setting the content manually)?

Comment: yes it is for all uploaded files. Tried with a separate entity and a different controller, but the same thing is happening. I am still looking into it, but clueless...

Comment: Alright... What about trying to serve a static file which would not have been uploaded by Vich? (Just to see if the problem comes from VichUploader, even though I don't think so)

Or the last thing I could see would be any invalid `Content-Type` header... Switching to `BinaryFileResponse` and removing the `setContent()` and `Content-Type: header` would solve this bug!